# Why Mathematica cannot solve this numerical integration?

Tags: numerical-integration, probability-or-statistics

I am trying to calculate the following integral. But, Mathematica does not output anything...

$\mathcal{L}=\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left\{-\mathbb{E}_h\left[\int_x^{\infty}\left(1-\exp\left(-\mu x^{\alpha}hz^{-\alpha}\right)\right)2\lambda\pi z \text{ d}z\right]\right\}2\lambda\pi x\exp(-\lambda\pi x^2)\text{ d}x$

$\bf{EDIT:}$ The correct form is

$\mathcal{L}=\int_0^{\infty}\exp\left(-2 \pi\lambda \int_x^{\infty}\left(1-\mathbb{E}_h[\exp\left(-\mu x^{\alpha}hz^{-\alpha}\right)]\right)z \text{ d}z\right)2\lambda\pi x\exp(-\lambda\pi x^2)\text{ d}x$

I am doing this....

```
\[Alpha] = 4;
\[Mu] = 3.1623;
\[Lambda] = 50;


NIntegrate[
 Exp[-Expectation[
     NIntegrate[(1 - 
         Exp[-\[Mu]*x^\[Alpha]*h*z^(-\[Alpha])])*2*\[Pi]*\[Lambda]*
       z, {z, x, Infinity}], 
     h \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]]*2*\[Pi]*\[Lambda]*
  x*Exp[-\[Pi]*\[Lambda]*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

$\bf{EDIT:}$ Now, I am doing this....Is it correct, I am getting 0.252313

```
 \[Alpha] = 4;
        \[Mu] = 3.1623;
        \[Lambda] = 50;

    NIntegrate[
 Exp[-2*\[Pi]*\[Lambda]*
   NIntegrate[(1 - 
       Expectation[Exp[-\[Mu]*x^\[Alpha]*h*z^(-\[Alpha])], 
        h \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]])*z, {z, x, 
     Infinity}]]*2*\[Pi]*\[Lambda]*
  x*Exp[-\[Pi]*\[Lambda]*x^2], {x, 0, Infinity}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make progress if we deconstruct the calculation and do as much symbolically as possible.  First, we try the innermost integral, as

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
α = 4;
f = Integrate[
  (1 - Exp[-μ*x^α*h*z^(-α)])*2*π*λ*z,
  {z, x, Infinity},
  Assumptions -> {x > 0, h > 0, μ > 0}]

(* π x^2 λ (-1 + E^(-h μ) + 
   Sqrt[π] Sqrt[h μ] Erf[Sqrt[h μ]])  *)
```

Notice that we set the value of `α` and tell `Integrate[]` that the other variables are positive, and therefore real.

The next step is to evaluate the `Expectation[]`.  When I see that error function in the result for `f`, I am not encouraged, but let's try it.

```
g = Expectation[f, h \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]]

(* π x^2 λ Sqrt[μ] ArcTan[Sqrt[μ]] *)
```

Very encouraging.  Now we try the numerical integration, as

```
λ = 50; μ = 3.1623;
NIntegrate[
  Exp[-g]*2*π*λ*x*Exp[-π*λ*x^2],
  {x, 0, Infinity}]

    (* 0.346937 *)
```

Hopefully, this is the desired solution to the originally stated problem.

***For the edited problem***, when we try to execute your code, MMA reminds us that there is a non-numerical expression in the integrand of `NIntegrate`.  This is because we are telling the inner `NIntegrate` to return a function of `x`.  We need to change it to `Integrate` and add the assumption that `x ∈ Reals`, as

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
α = 4;
μ = 3.1623;
λ = 50;

NIntegrate[Exp[-2*π*λ*
   Integrate[(1 - Expectation[
        Exp[-μ*x^α*h*z^(-α)],
        h \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[1]])*z,
    {z, x, Infinity},
     Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]],
 {x, 0, Infinity}]

(*  0.0515386  *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have edited my question, where I have an alternative form for the same problem. If the two solutions match, then only I will be able to confirm it. Will you please have a look at it and suggest me a way to solve it.

Comment: In an earlier version of my answer I said `Evaluate` was required, but this was incorrect.  I also said the assumption `x>0` was required, but this was also wrong.  The inner integral can be evaluated with `x ∈ Reals`.  My apologies for the misdirection.